# How to generate /usr/share/syslinux/{mbr.bin,ldlinux.c32} from scratch?

Tags: syslinux, mkisofs

Today, I have built `isolinux` from source code (git://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git) using command

```
make bios efi64 installer
```

During the building, I got some errors. For these errors, I must copy `/usr/share/syslinux/{mbr.bin,ldlinux.c32...}` to the appropriate directories.

Now I am curious how these files such as `mbr.bin` and `ldlinux.c32` are built from scratch？

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to include the error message you got? It would help contributors to understand your problem ...

Comment: @AdminBee, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are built from source: `mbr.bin` from [the files in `mbr`](https://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/tree/HEAD:/mbr), `ldlinux.c32` from [the files in `com32/elflink/ldlinux`](https://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/tree/HEAD:/com32/elflink/ldlinux), etc.

If your build failed, it’s probably because you didn’t have the tools required to build these: `nasm` and a multilib GCC in particular. `nasm` is used to assemble the MBR, and GCC has to support `-m32` to build the 32-bit loaders on a 64-bit platform.